# Completion Counting only Once

Tags: db2

Have an SQL query for DB2 that returns the timestamp of when an event completed. It completes at 2 different date/times, which is the result expected.

That result completes at those 2 different times for the same entity. I desire that the entity be counted one time for the purposes of my query.

How would I get the query to return the result for only the first instance of completion for that entity?

Comment: Can this have **only** two entries per entity? Per hour, per minute, per day, etc?  If only two (2) entries within a time period, choose the first

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what "first" means (or provide any table structure or example data), but let's assume it's the earliest completion timestamp:

```
  SELECT entity, min(completion_ts)
    FROM your_table
GROUP BY entity
```

If you are just getting results for a single entity, you can simplify even more:

```
  SELECT min(completion_ts)
    FROM your_table
   WHERE entity = 'XXX'
```

Comment: I am using the Min ( ) Over (Partition By) function. My results show both instances of the occurrence based on the timestamp. I am not retrieving for a single entity in that there are 5 viable entities. I need to obtain the first time it occurred in that entity.

Comment: I am using the Min ( ) Over (Partition By) function. My results show both instances of the occurrence based on the timestamp. I am not retrieving for a single entity in that there are 5 viable entities. I need to obtain the first time it occurred in that entity.  The data is coming from different tables. There is a CTE first pulling table from one table that is then referenced in a second CTE and joined to another table. This is where the result of the 2 instances occurs and I need to have just the first instance.

Comment: I am using the MIN () OVER (Partition By) here in the second but am not getting the differentiation of selecting first per entity.

Comment: Unless you post more information:  Query, DDL and example data, you won't get a definitive answer.